Why did my microcontroller emit smoke?
My setup is as follows: I have an RGB LED driver board powered by a 24V SMPS. The microcontroller, an ESP32, is connected to the driver board by RGBW PWM lines and a ground line. The ESP32 is also connected to a desktop PC via USB, which is used for flashing firmware and sending serial commands to an interface on the microcontroller.
Earlier today as I was flashing the ESP32, I plugged in the USB and it emitted magic smoke. The ESP32 ended up dead along with one of the drivers on the driver board. The driver board is fused with a 3A slow blow fuse that was still intact, so what occurred was pretty rapid. I also have a bidirectional TVS diode on the 24V input of the driver board.
My first thought was that this was some sort of ground reference issue. I checked the SMPS, and as I thought might be the case, the low side ground had continuity with the mains earth pin on the wall plug. The desktop USB ground is, I suspect, ground isolated.
Would this be sufficient to account for what happened here? What's the best practice for a device that needs to be both powered by switched 24V and has to talk to a computer over USB serial?

Generally desktop PCs have earthed plug, which earths the case and 0V ground return, including USB. Is your computer somehow special? You might want to give details which SMPS it is and how everything is connected together, including schematics of everything you can.

Please provide a schematic of your setup

USB on your PC is almost surely earthed and presumably at the same potential as the PSU low side (assuming your wall sockets etc. are properly wired). Is the 24V PSU low side connected to ground in your circuit? If it is not, then you have an explanation, otherwise it is a mystery and could therefore happen again.

We need to see a schematic of how power is derived for ESP32 and how USB provides power during programming.
